# Multi-variable Calculus: Domains and Critical Points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $z = 3(y+1)^2-2x^2$  on the domain bounded by the curves : $y = x$   and $ y = x^2-6 $

Sketch the domain.

Find and classify all critical points.

Find the global maximum and minimum.

I don't know how to solve this problem and I don't know any online resources that could help me learn this. Specifically problems bounded by two curves, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you solve the problem of the domain were, say, a circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain (region between $y=x$ and $y=x^2-6$):

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

The critical points of $z = 3(y+1)^2-2x^2$:
$$\begin{cases}z_x = -4x=0 \\ z_y=6y+6=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,-1) \quad \text{feasible}.$$
The critical points on the border $y=x$:
$$z(x)=3(x+1)^2-2x^2 \Rightarrow z_x=2x+6=0 \Rightarrow \\
(x,y)=(-3,-3) \quad \text{nonfeasible}$$
The critical points on the border $y=x^2-6$:
$$z(x)=3(x^2-5)^2-2x^2 \Rightarrow z_x=6(x^2-5)(2x)-4x=0 \Rightarrow \\
(x,y)=(0,-6) \ \text{feasible}; \left(\pm \sqrt{\frac{16}{3}};\frac23\right)\approx (\pm5.33;-0.67) \ \text{nonfeasible}$$
The corner points:
$$(x,y)=(-2;-2); (3;3) \ \text{feasible}$$
Can you check all feasible points and determine the maximum and minimum value of the objective function?